# How do I install the minimal facilities of Visual Studio 2008 sufficient for building C++ applications using Visual Studio 2010's multitargeting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Dev10 has facilities for using the C++ compiler shipped in Orcas. However, I really don't need to install the full IDE -- I merely need to use Orcas' compiler because I need to support Windows 2000.

What's the simplest way of installing just the bits required to build using Orcas' toolset in Dev10?

Comment: Is the full VS2010 really too much of an overhead for you? I think for the utility it gives you it must be around the most effecient usefulness/GB ratio out there!

Comment: Given the incredible complexity of Visual Studio, I have a feeling that even if you identified the precise components needed and extracted them, there's no guarantee that this will work properly.

Comment: You MAY only need to use Orcas' linker.  Or even `editbin`, to change the "minimum OS version" field in the PE header.  Are you statically or dynamically linking the CRT?

Comment: @JcMalta: I think he's going the other way round.  Install VS2010, but don't install 2008 (just compile w/ it).

Comment: @Ben: The CRT also adds dependencies on functions added in XP SP2.

Comment: @Billy: Yeah, I did a search and found the `EncodePointer`/`DecodePointer` mess, including a rather substantial bounty you awarded earlier this year.  Sorry to hear that stubbing those functions didn't work out well.  Is this the same update/maintenance checking program as the other question?  I'd lean toward using exclusively Win32 functions and not linking the CRT at all (have done this before successfully, although I wasn't trying to configure it with Win2k support I did get rid of all CRT dependencies).

Comment: @Ben: It might actually work -- it's just been difficult for me to test and I've elected to stick with something that works on code I'm shipping at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't installing the compiler from the DDK give you just the command line compiler and link, editbin, nmake etc?  May be worth a try if you have an older DDK around.

Answer (score 1):

Given your condition, I'd say just install VS2008 and use it. While it's not what you want it's the fastest path to working.

Comment: Maybe true, but this does not answer my question. (This belongs in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up Visual studio 2008 to work with Orcas compiler ? 
I'm sorry I don't know  about this very compiler, but I know it's possible to use VS2008 with a different compiler, because I tried it.

You can find plenty of doc on running VS2008 with, for example, the Windows SDK compiler or VS2010 compiler. For example that links explains that quite well : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105011/Using-Visual-Studio-2008-IDE-with-Visual-Cplusplus.aspx

HTH

Comment: "Orcas" IS "Visual Studio 2008".